# drop all rows when all cells are either zero or nan

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I need to remove all rows from a dataframe when all cells in each column for that row are either 0 or 'nan' (other than ID column which will be some unique value)
I have tried the command below but no luck.
The expected output is also pasted below.
Thank you in advance!

data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'a':[0,0,0,1], 'b':[0,1,'nan',1], 'c':['nan',1,0,1]})

    id  a   b   c
0   1   0   0   nan
1   2   0   1   1
2   3   0   nan 0
3   4   1   1   1
```

command

```
df.loc[df[(df != 0) & (df != ('nan'))].all(axis=1)]
```

expected output

```
    id  a   b   c
0   2   0   1   1
1   4   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be changed by select all columns without first with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df2 = df[(df1 != 0).all(axis=1) | (df1 != 'nan').all(axis=1)]
```

Working like [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df2 = df[~df.iloc[:, 1:].isin([0, 'nan']).all(axis=1)]
```

---

If `NaN` are missing values is necessary test them by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df2 = df[(df1 != 0).all(axis=1) | df1.notna().all(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df2 = df[~df.iloc[:, 1:].fillna('nan').isin([0, 'nan']).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) functions of Pandas.

```
df[~df.drop('id', 1).isin([0,'nan']).all(1)]
```

Output will be as follows:

```
   id  a  b  c
1  2   0  1  1 
3  4   1  1  1
```

***Explanation:***

- `df.drop('id', 1).isin([0,'nan']).all(1)`: Using `drop` function to drop at axis 1 to drop column id then checking if its values present in 0 or nan then using `all` to check if all values are TRUE then give true.
- Then using `~` to invert output of above mask to get expected output out of DataFrame.